# Decrypt the encrypted private key in pkcs #1 format

Tags: c#, .net-core, openssl, bouncycastle, x509certificate2

I have been give a private key certificate in a encrypted format. This certificate is encrypted using a passphrase.

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,10B1961116EC503A

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

I have this encrypted certificate as string in c# and would like to decrypt this certificate. How can we achieve this?

On Command line I used this command to decrypt this certificate

openssl rsa -in privatekey.enc -out privatekey.dec

and entered passphrase in the prompt

Answer (score 1):

This is an encrypted RSA private key in PKCS#1 format.

The encrypted PKCS#1 format is not supported by .NET (only the encrypted PKCS#8 format), see [`ImportFromEncryptedPem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importfromencryptedpem?view=net-7.0), *Remarks* section, and [`ImportEncryptedPkcs8PrivateKey()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importencryptedpkcs8privatekey?view=net-7.0).

However, C#/BouncyCastle supports encrypted private PKCS#1 keys (just like encrypted private PKCS#8 keys). The following C# code can handle both encryption formats:

```cs
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

...

string encPkcs1 = @"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,4E21D4111C06D936
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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(encPkcs1);
PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(stringReader, new PasswordFinder("password")); 

object pemObject = pemReader.ReadObject();
RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters rsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters = null;
if (pemObject is AsymmetricCipherKeyPair) // encrypted PKCS#1 key
{
    rsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)((AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)pemObject).Private;
}
else if (pemObject is RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters) // encrypted PKCS#8 key
{
    rsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)pemObject;
}
else
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Not supported: " + pemObject.ToString()); 
}

RSAParameters rsaParameters = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(rsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters);
using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
{
    rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
    Console.WriteLine(rsa.ExportRSAPrivateKeyPem());
}

...

private class PasswordFinder : IPasswordFinder
{
    private string password;
    public PasswordFinder(string pwd) => password = pwd;
    public char[] GetPassword() => password.ToCharArray();
}
```

and returns the unencrypted private key in PKCS#1 format as output in accordance with the following OpenSSL statement:

```
openssl rsa -passin pass:"<your password>" -in "<your path to encrypted key>" -out "<your path to key>"
```

---

For completeness: The decryption of the key can of course also be performed *explicitly*. The logic is the following (s. e.g. [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey.html), section *PEM ENCRYPTION FORMAT*):

- DEK-Info specifies algorithm (Triple DES in CBC mode) and hex encoded IV (*0x10B1961116EC503A*).
- The key is derived using the OpenSSL proprietary key derivation function `EVP_BytesToKey`, with the digest MD5, the IV (more precisely the first 8 bytes) as salt and an iteration count of 1.
- The Base64 encoded ciphertext is the data that follows the DEK info.

There are several C# implementations for `EVP_BytesToKey()` on the web. A reliable one is the one from BouncyCastle. A C# sample code for decryption using BouncyCastle is:

```cs
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Generators;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

...

// Derive Triple DES key
char[] password = "password".ToCharArray();
byte[] salt = Convert.FromHexString("4E21D4111C06D936");
int iterationCount = 1;

PbeParametersGenerator pbeParametersGenerator = new OpenSslPbeParametersGenerator(new MD5Digest());
pbeParametersGenerator.Init(PbeParametersGenerator.Pkcs5PasswordToBytes(password), salt, iterationCount);
ParametersWithIV parametersWithIV = (ParametersWithIV)pbeParametersGenerator.GenerateDerivedParameters("DESede", 192, 64); // key: 24 bytes, IV: 8 bytes
KeyParameter keyParameter = (KeyParameter)parametersWithIV.Parameters;

byte[] key = keyParameter.GetKey();
// byte[] iv = parametersWithIV.GetIV();
byte[] iv = salt; // the algorithm doesn't apply the IV derived but the IV specified in the DEK Info

// Decrypt RSA key
byte[] ciphertext = Convert.FromBase64String("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");
byte[] decrypted = null;
using (TripleDES tripleDes = TripleDES.Create())
using (ICryptoTransform transform = tripleDes.CreateDecryptor(key, iv))
{
    decrypted = transform.TransformFinalBlock(ciphertext, 0, ciphertext.Length);
}

// Export RSA key in PKCS#1 format
using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
{
    rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(decrypted, out _);
    Console.WriteLine(rsa.ExportRSAPrivateKeyPem());
}
```

Above sample code exports the unencrypted private key in PKCS#1 format.